# how set a global variable depends on parameter?

Tags: ios

I have some NSString Globals variables.

I can set them like that:

```
[[Globals sharedInstance] setColor1:@"red"];
[[Globals sharedInstance] setColor2:@"orange"];
```

But i am in a function, with a parameter who represent the number 1, 2, 3, etc.
How can i do something like that ?

```
[[Globals sharedInstance] setColorMYPARAMETER:@"orange"];
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not possible. But you can try another approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the selector based on the method name dynamically, using `NSSelectorFromString`:

```
int colorNum = ... ;
NSString * colorSelStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setColor%d:", colorNum];
[[Globals sharedInstance] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(colorSelStr) withObject:@"orange"];
```

This will create a string that looks like the method name you want, and then you ask the shared global object to "performSelector" with the SEL that comes from that string, giving the color string as argument.

---

However, this probably indicates that you could design the original code a little better. Why do you have globals numbered 0-n? Why not keep an `NSArray` for all the global colors and then just access it by index?

Comment: forgot colon after setColor string

Comment: looks good, but i have a warning, perfomSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknow, i guess it doesn't matter

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Globals setColor3]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.  stange because my globals variables NSString *color3 does exist

Comment: @ChHnsn: try it now-- I'd forgotten a colon at the end of the selector name.

Comment: @ChHnsn that is just a small warning that occurs that is completely harmless. If you want it to go away look up how to suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SEL mySel =NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"setColor%d:",num]);
[[Globals sharedInstance] performSelector:mySel withObject:@"color"];
```